# из JSON в Realm

Tags: json, swift, realm

салют, цель: заполнить БД реалма данными из джэйсона; в джэйсоне 20 объектов (массивы) в каждом по 6 элементов; при заполнении БД икскод дает ошибку Thread 1: "Invalid array input: more values (20) than properties (6)." Как сделать чтобы в реалме создалось 20 записей по 6 элементов?

```
//структура ДЖСОН
struct Person: Codable{
    let results: [Result]
}
struct Result: Codable{
    let personID: Int
    let personName: String
    let personStatus: String
    let personSpecies: String
    let location: Location
    let personImageURL: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case personID = "id"
        case personName = "name"
        case personStatus = "status"
        case personSpecies = "species"
        case location
        case personImageURL = "image"
    }
}
struct Location: Codable {
    let personLocation: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case personLocation = "name"
    }
}
//класс РЕАЛМ
class RMRealmClass: Object{
    @objc dynamic var personIDRealm = Int()
    @objc dynamic var personNameRealm = String()
    @objc dynamic var personStatusRealm = String()
    @objc dynamic var personSpeciesRealm = String()
    @objc dynamic var personImageURLRealm = String()
    @objc dynamic var personLocationRealm = String()
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "personIDRealm"
    }
}

class CollectionViewController_d: UICollectionViewController {

    @IBOutlet var RMCollection: UICollectionView!
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var persons2: Results<RMRealmClass>{
        get{return realm.objects(RMRealmClass.self)}
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadData()
    }
//метод ДЖСОН + РЕАЛМ
    func loadData(){
        AF.request("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character").responseJSON { response in
            guard let data = response.data else {return}
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                do {
                    let persons = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: data)
                    try! self.realm.write{
                        self.realm.create(RMRealmClass.self, value: persons.results)
                    }
                }
                catch let error {print (error)}
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage
import RealmSwift
//структура json
struct Person: Codable{
    let results: [Result]
}
struct Result: Codable{
    let personID: Int
    let personName: String
    let personStatus: String
    let personSpecies: String
    let location: Location
    let personImageURL: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case personID = "id"
        case personName = "name"
        case personStatus = "status"
        case personSpecies = "species"
        case location
        case personImageURL = "image"
    }
}
struct Location: Codable {
    let personLocation: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case personLocation = "name"
    }
}
// class Realm
class RMRealmClass: Object{
    @objc dynamic var personIDRealm = Int()
    @objc dynamic var personNameRealm = String()
    @objc dynamic var personStatusRealm = String()
    @objc dynamic var personSpeciesRealm = String()
    @objc dynamic var personImageURLRealm = String()
    @objc dynamic var personLocationRealm = String()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "personIDRealm"
    }
}
class CollectionViewController_d: UICollectionViewController {
    @IBOutlet var RMCollection: UICollectionView!
//создание экземпляра класса Realm
    let realm = try! Realm()
//получение данных хранящихся в Realm для первичного заполнения таблицы
    var persons2: Results<RMRealmClass>{
        get{return realm.objects(RMRealmClass.self)}
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//реализация метода получения json и парсинга его в Realm
        loadData ()
        RMCollection.reloadData()
    }
//метод получения json и парсинга его в Realm
    func loadData(){
        AF.request("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character").responseJSON { response in
            guard let data = response.data else {return}
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                do {
                    let persons = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: data)
                        for result in persons.results{
                            try! self.realm.write{
                                    let rmRealm = RMRealmClass()
                                            rmRealm.personIDRealm = result.personID
                                            rmRealm.personNameRealm = result.personName
                                            rmRealm.personStatusRealm = result.personStatus
                                            rmRealm.personSpeciesRealm = result.personSpecies
                                            rmRealm.personLocationRealm = result.location.personLocation
                                            rmRealm.personImageURLRealm = result.personImageURL
                                    self.realm.add(rmRealm, update: .modified)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                catch let error {print (error)}
            }
        }
    }
// получаем количество ячеек коллекции
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return persons2.count
    }
//заполнение коллекции
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell_d
        let person = persons2[indexPath.item]
        cell.name.text = person.personNameRealm
        cell.status.text = person.personStatusRealm
        cell.species.text = person.personSpeciesRealm
        cell.location.text = person.personLocationRealm
        let url = URL(string: person.personImageURLRealm) ?? URL(string: "здесь размещаем ссылку на дефолтное изображение")!
        cell.image.af.setImage(withURL: url)
        cell.logo.image = UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill")
        switch person.personStatusRealm{
            case String("Alive"): cell.logo.tintColor = .green
            case String("unknown"): cell.logo.tintColor = .orange
            default: cell.logo.tintColor = .red
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если это ответ, то, пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. а если это дополнение к вопросу, то измениет вопрос, а этот «ответ» удалите.

Comment: Это ответ или дополнение к вопросу?

Comment: это вариант кода, который работает и отвечает на поставленный вопрос